# TypeError when trying to set a property of a Struct (Nashorn, Kafka Connect transformer)

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, nashorn

Using Kafka Connect (`6.1.1`), I'm trying to use [Sergey34/kafka-connect-transformers](https://github.com/Sergey34/kafka-connect-transformers) to adjust my Kafka messages before putting them into BigQuery (using BigQuerySink).

In my `connector.properties`, I configure `ScriptEngineTransformer` as follows (minimized example):

```
transforms=scriptenginetransformer
transforms.scriptenginetransformer.type=seko.kafka.connect.transformer.script.ScriptEngineTransformer
transforms.scriptenginetransformer.scrip_engine_name=javascript
transforms.scriptenginetransformer.value.script=function valueTransform(source){ source.foo = 42; return source;}
```

But at runtime I get the following error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property "foo" of Struct{a=111,b=222} in <eval> at line number 2
```

(stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/117f31f17a6e1ac419b3245fadc7eda5))

From my rudimentary understanding of JS, I'd think it should be possible to replace or add properties to a struct, i.e., the following of course works fine (in a sandbox):

```js
function Foo(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

foo = new Foo(1, 2);
foo.y = 3;
foo.z = 4;

console.log(foo);
```

It looks like my (Avro) Kafka message (`{a=111,b=222}`) is correctly passed to the JS script. So what could this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a static field, Kafka comes with a built-in transform to do exactly that...

Regarding your issue, reading the code, it never tests or uses records that have schemas, and never builds a new Struct type

Therefore, I think your input is limited to primitive schema types such as string/integer/boolean

In other words, `"Struct{a=111,b=222}" + "foo"` would "work fine" and you'd end up `"Struct{a=111,b=222}foo"` but the string representation of the Avro record, `"Struct{a=111,b=222}"`, has no Javascript property `foo`, and so it can't be set

Your alternative/workaround would be to make sure that you're consuming with the standard JSONConverter, then using `JSON.parse` to build an object that you can set JS properties into

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense to me too. I've finally managed to convince myself that it's better to write an actual custom SMT instead of trying to achieve my goals by plugging together crazy 3rd-party stuff. :-D And with [this tutorial](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/) together with the provided example code it's actually not that hard. :)